# Hide new vNet option in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am creating a solution template for our offering and I need to allow customer to choose an existing virtual network from the list.

I am using 'Microsoft.Network.VirtualNetworkCombo' UI element but it allows option to create a new vNet as well. But I want customer to only select existing vNet.

Is there any option available to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no picker elements for existing elements. nothing you can do about it.